# How can display a sub-menu to hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/?product_category=printing)

If you click on Products,appeear a sub-menu.

I want to do the same when the arrow is over the menu (hover).

I tried to use this code in JQuery but doesn`t work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //$("#menu-main-menu li").hover(function(){
    //jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').show(1000);
    //}, function(){
    // jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
 //$("body").click(function() {
   // $(".sub-menu").hide(1000);
//});


  //here begins the code I tried I

    $("#menu-main-menu li").hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).delay(1000).show(0);
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).delay(1000).hide(0);
    });



    });
```

Implementation is something wrong?
You can help me tell me where I was wrong for not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$("#menu-main-menu li").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).delay(1000).show(0);
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').stop(true,true).delay(1000).hide(0);
});



});
```

Explanation :

I just delete "});"